# Extract first sentence from string of text

Tags: regex, string

Is there a simple trick to isolate the first sentence in a large string of text?  (Perhaps using regular expressions.)

Searching for the first fullstop "." doesn't work, as acronyms such as "U.S.A." will screw things up.

(There probably is no right answer.)

Answer (score 12):

No. There is no simple trick. To do this properly, you need to do a syntactic analysis of the text. Nobody can do that. At least not yet. At least not 100% of the time. Mainly because it also entails a semantic analysis of the text. You see, contrary to what the type of linguists that taught you grammar in school think, what makes up a sentence is pretty hard to sum up in a set of rules a computer could follow without understanding the text.

Spend the next couple of years looking up computational linguistics. Maybe by then there will be a shortcut?

**But you can get close.**

I'd probably try to look for the first period, question mark or exclamation mark followed by whitespace.

```
/^(.*?)[.?!]\s/
```

(The `(.*?)` is a non-greedy regex, to make sure you really do only find the first sentence.

Comment: This regex would fail if the sentence contained an acronym such as U.S.A. mid sentence. :)

Comment: @pauldoo, you're right. I was only guarding (with the `\s`) against the first two punctuation characters :(

Answer (score 9):

It can't be done in a guaranteed manner, but this will get you quite close with a relatively simple expression:

```
/(^.*?[a-z]{2,}[.!?])\s+\W*[A-Z]/
```

Starting at the beginning of the line (`^`) it non-greedily looks for any number of arbitrary characters (`.*?`) ending with at least two lowercase letters (`[a-z]{2,}`) and a period, question mark, or exclamation mark (`[.!?]`), followed by one or more spaces (`\s+`), zero or more non-word characters e.g. opening parenthesis (`\W*`) and a capital letter (`[A-Z]`).

This will avoid premature truncation due to acronyms, assuming they:

- are capitalized, as in "U.S.A."
- are lowercase but individual letters, as in "e.g." or "i.e."
- or are followed by lowercase letter, as in "This abbr. stands for abbreviation."

One shortcoming is that it won't stop if a sentence ends with a punctuated uppercase acronym or an abbreviation, but for it's simplicity and effectiveness this seems like a fair tradeoff.

Answer (score 5):

Would you pay for this being done? If so se Amazon's Mechanical Turk which farms tasks out to real people at a rate, lets say $0.01 per update. At least it beats the hell out of doing two years computational linguistics. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will lookup for the first full stop that does not follow a capital letter. But this wont work with some abbreviations.

There is no magical solution… you could make a list of all abbreviations and ignore them when followed by a full stop.

Answer (score 1):

Like said before, there is no easy solution.

A more enhanced version of a regex could be: `/^(.*?(?<!\b\w)[.?!])\s+[A-Z0-9]/`. It does not stop at mid sentence acronyms (but also not, if they are at the end of a sentence...), the next sentence has to start with an upper case letter oder digit....

If you know a list of acronyms that you dont want your regex to stop at, you migth add them like:  `/^(.*?(?<!\b\w|U\.S\.A|eg)[.?!])\s+[A-Z0-9]/`.

If you know what language you are going to use, there might be some Natural Language Parsing (NLP) toolkit - but this would go beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Bayes solution such as Splitta ( http://code.google.com/p/splitta/ ) or in the Ruby world, the Tactful Tokenizer ( https://github.com/SlyShy/Tactful_Tokenizer ).

Answer (score 1):

This will nicely do it. Takes string and split it

```
"Men are born free. Everywhere in Chains".split('. ', 1)[0]
```

Abbreviations won't be considered as first sentence with this example

Answer (score 0):

Using a plain text string theres not guranteed way to do it, but using a string with some masking for example if your string has \n at the end of each line or sentence you can use that to determine an end to the line, other than that you have to just guess it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You can also find a working [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/chrisN/pen/jzjpao)

**HTML**

```
<div id="original">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, U.S.A adipiscing elit. Phasellus nulla magna, suscipit dapibus bibendum sit amet.
</div></br> 

<div id="results"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var s = document.getElementById('original').innerHTML

var t = s.split('. ', 1)[0]

console.log(t)

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

The method takes into account the dot symbols inside the sentence: U.S.A etc.

Also added an optional parameter for the minimum length of the result string.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the first sentence from the text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The text.</param>
/// <param name="minLength">The minimum length of the sentence.</param>
public static string FirstSentence(this string text, int minLength = 10)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var sentences = Regex.Split(text, @"(.[^\.\!\?]*(?>\.[^\s\.][^\.\!\?]+)*[\.\!\?]*)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        .Select(s => s.Trim())
        .ToArray();

    var result = string.Empty;

    foreach (var s in sentences)
    {
        result = $"{result} {s}".Trim();

        if (result.Length >= minLength)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you assume that acronyms have no spaces between the periods? If so, this will work:

```
string.split('. ').first
```

e.g.

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, U.S.A adipiscing elit. Phasellus nulla magna, suscipit dapibus bibendum sit amet."
s.split('. ').first

=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, U.S.A adipiscing elit"
```

Note that it strips the trailing period.

Comment: In your example, you leave the last period in "U.S.A." out, so this doesn't solve the problem. If the acronym were properly punctuated, it would cut off after "U.S.A.", not making it all the way to "elit".

Comment: This doesn't work if the first sentence ends with a `? or !` either.